# PostgreSQL log filename

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL version 10.16 on Ubuntu 18.04

In the postgresq.conf, I set
`log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log' # log file name pattern,`

After restarted database, I only see `postgresql-10-main.log` in the log directory.

Btw, I restarted the database using this command:

`/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main restart`

Anything I missed?

Comment: Most likely you have more than one config file, and edited the wrong one.  Or maybe the file (and any included files) have more than one log_filename, and you edited the non-prevailing one.

Comment: I'm going to assume you are using some Debian/Ubuntu version(please update question with this information) and you are using the Postgres(PGDG) repo.  Questions: 1) Where was the `postgresql.conf` you changed located? 2) What happens if you use `pg_ctlcluster 10 main <action>`?

Comment: I changed postgresql.conf in two locations:
`/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf`
and 
`/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf`

and diff shows identical
`diff /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf`
`
also did `pg_ctlcluster 10 main restart` still don't see new log file name.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using the Debian or Ubuntu binaries. The packager decided to leave `logging_collector = off`, so `log_filename` is ignored. Rather, the standard error from the PostgreSQL processes is collected in the log file you see.

If you change `logging_collector` to `on` and restart PostgreSQL, it will use the configured log file.

Comment: It works after changed `logging_collector = on` Thank you so much for your help!